# CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS in JOCL (a Java Binding to OpenCL).

Tags: java, opencl, gpgpu, matrix-multiplication, jocl

Anybody encounter this kind of error on doing Matrix Multiplication in JOCL?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jocl.CLException: CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS
at org.jocl.CL.checkResult(CL.java:787)
at org.jocl.CL.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CL.java:20802)
at org.jocl.samples.JOCLSample.main(JOCLSample.java:147)
```

I edited their sample HelloJOCL.java to do a Matrix Multiplication calculations also the matrixMul.cl (Kernel Code). Here is the Kernel arguments that cause the error:

```
// Create the kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "matrixMul", null);

    long time = nanoTime();
    // Set the arguments for the kernel
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, 
        Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[0]));
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, 
        Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[1]));
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, 
        Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[2]));
```

The work item dimensions code:

```
// Set the work-item dimensions
    long global_work_size[] = new long[]{n};
    long local_work_size[] = new long[]{1};


// Execute the kernel
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, null,
    global_work_size, null, 0, null, null);
```

And the Kernel Code:

```
private static String programSource =
        "__kernel void "+
                "matrixMul(__global float* C,"+ 
                "          __global float* A,"+ 
                "          __global float* B,"+ 
                "          int wA, int wB)"+
                "{"+
                   "int x = get_global_id(0);"+ 
                   "int y = get_global_id(1);"+

                   "float value = 0;"+
                   "for (int k = 0; k < wA; ++k)"+
                   "{"+
                   "   float elementA = A[y * wA + k];"+
                   "   float elementB = B[k * wB + x];"+
                   "   value += elementA * elementB;"+
                   "}"+
                  "C[y * wA + x] = value;"+
                "}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel function is defined as

```
__kernel void matrixMul(__global float* C,
                        __global float* A,
                        __global float* B,
                        int wA, int wB)
```

and thus expects *five* arguments. You are only providing the first *three* arguments, namely the memory objects that represent the `float*` values. In order to launch this kernel, you will have to pass in values for **all** arguments. In your case, this could roughly look like this:

```
int a=0;
clSetKernelArg(kernel, a++, 
    Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[0]));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, a++, 
    Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[1]));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, a++, 
    Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(memObjects[2]));

// These have been missing:
clSetKernelArg(kernel, a++, 
    Sizeof.cl_int, Pointer.to(new int[]{ wA }));
clSetKernelArg(kernel, a++, 
    Sizeof.cl_int, Pointer.to(new int[]{ wB }));
```

Comment: Thanks @Marco13. The program runs now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel code shows 5 input arguments, C,A,B,wA wB.
But I only see 3 clSetKernelSrg calls listed here.